# Process For Receiving SMS Messages On Android

Tags: android, sms

I apologize ahead of time if this is a open question, I have no where else to turn.

The question, in short, is this: How can I access the incoming SMS messages on an Android phone without being the default SMS messenger? Apps like Pushbullet do NOT request being a default app and they manage to work somehow. I would like to achieve the same result.

I went all over this site, and others, to aid in solving this issue. I am trying to develop an app that will process SMS messages once a user has received them to their phone. This "process" involves parsing it, and sending it over Bluetooth to a PC with a Python app running (this part works superb).
With the changes in Android's API I can NO LONGER user a BroadcastReceiver to intercept received SMS messages (using SMS_RECEIVED permission), since this will only be sent to the default SMS app or my current default app is killing the broadcast. **I do not want to make my app a default SMS app** so I am trying to find a work around to getting SMS messages from the phone.

After research I have come back with these options:

1. There is something I missed and I **can** use a BroadcastReceiver but I am doing it wrong.
2. I listen to the notifications on the phone and when an SMS message comes in I use Telephony.SMS to access the inbox to get the message (no idea if this works or if it is a preferred strategy).
3. (This is hard to find info on) Can I create a service that will intercept these messages **above** my current default SMS app?
4. Something else someone can come up with.

Please let me know if you have any questions or need elaboration of any kind, and thanks ahead of time!

**EDIT:**

A BroadcastReceiver is the way to go! It took some modification and the right permissions with the new permission model and voila!

Comment: You should be able to receive messages as long as you declare the permissions appropriately and setup everything to handle incoming messages. If you upped your SDK to 23, did you also include the newly required permissions changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. There is something I missed and I can use a BroadcastReceiver but I am doing it wrong.

Yep. Any app can still get the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast. In fact, this is more reliable now than in pre-KitKat versions, as that broadcast can no longer be aborted, so every app registered to receive it will get it.

If your Receiver is statically registered in the manifest, be sure to run your app at least once after installation to bring it out of the *stopped* state, otherwise your Receiver won't be delivered the broadcast. Also, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or above, and you're running under API 23+, you need to take into account Marshmallow's [new permissions model](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

> 2. I listen to the notifications on the phone and when an SMS message comes in I use Telephony.SMS to access the inbox to get the message (no idea if this works or if it is a preferred strategy).

This isn't the most reliable strategy, since the user can disable notifications for any app they choose.

> 3. (This is hard to find info on) Can I create a service that will intercept these messages above my current default SMS app?

Nope. The default SMS app gets the `SMS_DELIVER` broadcast, and it is the only app to receive it. You cannot intercept it, but there's no need to, given that the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast is still available.

> 4. Something else someone can come up with.

See #1.

Comment: First off, thank you very much for your reply Mike M. After reading your response I attempted to implement my own SMS receiver using the intent filter android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED, but for the life of me cannot seem to get a response when I run the app and get a message. I had this slight feeling like my HTC's default app was/is killing the broadcast. What are your thoughts on how to handle this issue? If you want to see me code/manifest let me know.
I also gave my app SMS permissions in android as well, by the way.

Comment: Ok so I managed to get the SMS receiver to work! So happy! Now my problem is with android permissions. For some reason, in my onCreate for the MainActivity, the only way I can prompt for a "allow SMS permission?" is if I do a wait for a few seconds before calling requestPermissions. Otherwise it skips right over it. Any help would be great...